# Overriding a method(with the same signature) present in both Parent Class as well as the Interface

Tags: java, overriding

We have a `Class`(say `Animal`), and we have an `Interface`(say `Behave`). Both `Animal` as well as `Behave` have a method with the same signature(say `public void eat()`).

When we try to write the body for the method `eat()` in a `Class`(say `Dog`) which `extends Animal` and `implements Behave`, which `eat()` method is actually referred to? The one in `Animal` or `Behave`. In whichever case that happens, why does it happen that way?

**Edit:**

I tried this scenario on `Eclipse` before posting this question.

An interesting part here is, even though I am implementing `Behave`, if I dont create an `eat()` method(i.e. if I dont implement `Behave's` inherited abstract method) inside `Dog`, there is no error, since I am already extending from `Animal` which has an `eat()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by "which method `eat()` is actually referred to?" In a way it refers to both; you override the method of `Animal` and you provide an implementation of the (itself abstract) method given by your interface `Behave`. Your question isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

`which eat() method is actually referred to?` BOTH.

Try this: if you don't override the method at all, when you call with the interface, you will get the one from the parent.

```
Behave b = new Dog();
System.out.println(b.eat());//this will call eat from Animal if Dog did not override.
```

If you override, you always get the one from the child:

```
Behavior b = new Dog();
Animal a = new Dog();

a.eat() and b.eat() will both refer to the eat inside of Dog class.
```

---

USE THESE CLASSES:

```
public class BClass {
public int add(int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}
}

public interface BInterface {
public int add(int a, int b);
}

public class BChild extends BClass implements BInterface{
public static void main(String... args){
    BInterface bi = new BChild();
    BClass bc = new BChild();
    System.out.println(bi.add(3, 5));
    System.out.println(bi.add(3, 5));
}

@Override
public int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had tried that on Eclipse before posting this question. An interesting part here is, even though I am implementing an interface, if I dont create an eat() method(which means I am implementing the interface's method) inside Dog, there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

interface can contain only body definition of method , once you implements, it must have implementation of all defined methods. In you example

```
class Dog extends Animal implements Behave
{
    @Override
    public void eat() {...}
 }

 abstract class Animal{
    public abstract void eat();
 }
 interface Behave{
    void eat();
 }
```

Here it need a body of abstract method where as it is in Main method. In other way

```
class DOG extends Animal implements Behave{
    ...
}

class Animal{
   public  void eat(){
        ...
   }
}

interface Behave{
    void eat();
}
```

Here Dog class having eat method body in its super class Animal. So it wount ask to implement body again in Animal as it is already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

An interface simply defines a method that a class must provide. If we have

```
public class Animal{
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("Om nom nom");
    }
}
public class Dog extends Animal{

}
```

Dog now provides the eat method and can so implement `Behave`.

Comment: That is, if Dog extends Animal

Comment: @Boosty Hah, yes. Missed out the most important part ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `eat()` method, because the designers of the language decided that the simplicity of having the method signature consist of its name and argument types was more useful than having the complexity of being able to specify that you are providing an implementation of an interface.

In Java, if the two have different semantics, provide a method which returns a Behave instance which does something else:

```
class Animal { 
    public void eat () { }
}

interface Behave { 
    void eat (); 
}

class Dog extends Animal { 
    public void eat () { 
        // override of Animal.eat()
    } 

    public Behave getBehave() { 
        return new Behave { 
            public void eat() { 
                BehaveEat(); 
            } 
        };
    }

    private void BehaveEat() {
        // effectively the implementation Behave.eat()
    }
}
```

In other languages, you can explicitly state that a method implements a method from an interface.